# Is ZeroMQ a good choice to make a Python app and a C# managed assembly work together?

Tags: c#, .net, python, sockets, message-queue

I have a task that involves talking to a .NET-based API (namely AutoCAD) to retrieve data, send commands, and react to events.

I want to separate the API operations and the proper program logic (largely already implemented in Python) by using natural tools for both: a C# DLL for the former and a Python app for the latter.

To connect these two pieces, I began exchanging JSON in ZeroMQ messages. I'm at early development stages but having recently discovered that ZeroMQ does not guarantee message delivery/order, I have reservations about whether this is a feasible way to go. Right now my app is a very basic REQ/REP pair and I plan to handle reacting to events and executing different commands by adding some sort of 'recipient-function' field to my message format.

The reason that I want to use ZMQ is that I might be able to scale the software into a larger, multi-user, distributed solution sometime.

I am a lay programmer so I would ask for your advice about this architecture. Should I just go ahead with it and plan to deal with message reliability/ordering when problems appear? Should I consider developing some kind of a REST wrapper around ZMQ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just worth writing this in C# or F#?

Comment: I understand your concern but yes, I'm pretty sure. My reasons are having almost zero experience in C#, much better authoring productivity in Python and the need to show a proof-of-concept to automate AutoCAD with Python scripts.

It seems that I practically end up writing a socket-based wrapper around C# methods but I want to give it a try anyways.

Comment: http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/ - Do both. Write a .NET Assembly using the Python language.

Comment: [Tried and failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858901/connecting-to-a-net-interface-using-python-instead-of-ironpython). I don't know if it's my inability to implement the binding to .NET correctly or there are objective issues with PythonNET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZeroMQ probably wouldn't be my first choice for this, but it should be doable.  The ZeroMQ manual has a section on reliability with REQ/REP sockets is there something you need beyond that?  As far as ordering goes would a simple 1 up counter work?  It would work more or less like TCP does if you receive a message before its time hold on to it and wait for the earlier message and perhaps send a response asking for a repeat of the missing message.

Comment: Thanks, that's valuable feedback. Any additional advice on what alternatives I could explore? It needs mentioning that the target is a Windows desktop so I try to avoid adding any demon processes that are (to my understanding) involved in using RabbitMQ or similar message brokers.

Comment: The ZMQ manual on reliablility (chapter 4) is awesome, I overlooked it! So, doable then. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#reliable-request-reply

Comment: @AlexBausk  You might investigate MSMQ.  It has a max message size of 4MB so it may not work depending on how big your messages can get.  It is built into the OS so deployment is relatively easy.

Comment: They can get pretty big (thousands of graphical entities with attributes). I think I'll stick with ZeroMQ, thanks!